# display activity from other application on my own application

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity

I would like to start an application (example Calculator) on a fragment for example on my application.

I try this code but i get an error (line Fragment):

```
String packageName = "com.android.calculator2";
Context ctx = getApplicationContext().createPackageContext(packageName, Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE |
                Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
        ClassLoader cl = ctx.getClassLoader();
        Class<?> c = cl.loadClass("com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
        Fragment fragObj = (Fragment)c.newInstance();
```

i get this error:

Process: fr.jm.managercamera, PID: 14006
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fr.jm.managercamera/fr.jm.managercamera.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.calculator2.Calculator cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)

I try this code, i get other problem:

Class requiredClass = null;
            final String apkPath = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.android.calculator2",0).sourceDir;

```
        final File dexTemp = getDir("temp_folder", 0);
        final String fullName = "com.android.calculator2.Calculator";
        boolean isLoaded = true;

        // Check if class loaded
        try {
            requiredClass = Class.forName(fullName);
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            isLoaded = false;
        }

        if (!isLoaded) {
            System.out.println("apkPath: " + apkPath);
            System.out.println("dexTemp.getAbsolutePath(): " + dexTemp.getAbsolutePath());
            final DexClassLoader classLoader = new DexClassLoader(apkPath,
                    dexTemp.getAbsolutePath(),
                    null,
                    getClass().getClassLoader());

           /* DexClassLoader classLoader = new DexClassLoader(apkPath,"/tmp", null,
                    getClass().getClassLoader());*/

            requiredClass = classLoader.loadClass(fullName);
        }
```

I get this error (line loadClass):

10-03 17:50:22.776 14133-14133/? W/System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.calculator2.Calculator" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/app/Calculator/Calculator.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
10-03 17:50:22.776 14133-14133/? W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
10-03 17:50:22.776 14133-14133/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
10-03 17:50:22.776 14133-14133/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. You can launch the calculator as an `Activity`, but you cannot load foreign code into your own OS process. That would be a security violation.

The calculator app's code is only allowed to run in the calculator app's OS Process, not in any other OS Process. The Android security model doesn't allow that.

Comment: What is the link explain, it's possible? : https://www.codota.com/code/java/classes/dalvik.system.DexClassLoader